# Communication between out of browser silverlight application and console application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have an out of browser silverlight application and a console application(This can be any other .NET application). I want to establish the communication between these two applications. Basically, I want to send a message from console app to out of browser app. and vice versa. Is this possible in SL 4 ? Does SL 5 has any new features to support this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1

Could a local WCF(HTTP, TCP, MSMQ, Named pipe) service hosted in the console app work?
(connect/poll)

## 2

Since SL4/5 supports interop you could use named pipes 
http://pendsevikram.blogspot.com/2010/01/silverlight-4-com-interopendless.html
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createnamedpipe